# Rails SQL to Postgresql with auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm migrating a SQL database in the following way:

```
class CitiesRelation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change

    self.connection.execute %Q(

    -- Create Table --

CREATE TABLE Cities (
  Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Code INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

-- Insert Data --

Insert into Cities (Code, Name, State) values ('1100015','City_1', 'A');
Insert into Cities (Code, Name, State) values ('1100023','City_2', 'B');
Insert into Cities (Code, Name, State) values ('1100031','City_3', 'C');

)

end 

end
```

And after the migration shows this error message:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
LINE 6:   Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                          ^
```

What is the best approach to solve this problem? I'm wondering to do it via seed but I don't know how. Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to execute raw sql, make sure you supply code in the corresponding dialect. This looks like mysql dialect.

Comment: Why are you not using activerecord migration DSL, again?

Comment: Hi @SergioTulentsev, sorry but I don't know where it is specified the dialect or how it can influence the result, and what you mean with activerecord migration DSL?

Comment: I mean, you're sending a flavor of sql that your postgresql won't understand. You have an example of AR DSL in the accepted answer (the `create_table :cities`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following **pg 9.6**

```
CREATE TABLE Cities (
    Id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Code INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    State CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

**pg 10 or latter**

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    Id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Code INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    State CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Why you not trying rails normal way like

```
class CitiesRelation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :Code, null: false
      t.string :Name, null: false
      t.string :State, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Rails by default creating `id`

Then `rake db:migrate`

Here are the [rails doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: @FillypeFarias, I have edited the answer, check it out, please let me know is this helped you

Comment: Your last post answered the question and sorry for that.